# bash: code: command not found

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

On a windows 8.1, prefer mac. Just downloaded visual studio code.  Git Bash installed.  If I type `code`, VS Code should open up a new file, but bash is telling me it doesn't know of that command.  Restarting/reinstalling didn't help.  When I downloaded, the option to add it to the PATH was selected.  What do I need to do to add this command so I can open directories from the command prompt?

Comment: Right now, people who know bash but not VS Code can't help with this at all. Adding more details would help. Does comparing `echo %PATH%` inside `cmd.exe` to `echo "$PATH"` in bash, for instance, show you that the relevant addition is present inside one but not the other? If you search for `code.exe` (`code.bat`, etc), where is it installed?

Answer (score 3):

Launching via Git Bash is not currently supported, this is being tracked in [issue #1704](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1704) on GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

> facing same problem but found solution on git

[download now](https://git-scm.com/)